# How to register spring-boot app to consul over https?

Tags: spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

Can someone please provide the configuration (all the necessary steps) which are needed to make a spring-boot service register to consul over https.

I have configured Consul to https port 8501. However, setting up the following,

spring.cloud.consul.port=8501
spring.cloud.consul.scheme=https

is not sufficient. I am certain that I need to use certificates but can self-signed certificates be used? if yes then I do I make consul trust the self-signed certificates?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The closest response that I found over the internet was from the following post,

https://warlord3112.wordpress.com/2018/04/30/mutual-tls2-way-between-consul-and-spring-boot-application/

With some slight modification to the steps defined in the above link, it can be successfully used to establish both way SSL communication with Consul.